# Android realm prevent exception with .first() method and empty database

Tags: android, exception, realm

Do you know how to prevent exception when using

```
            Synchronization synchronization = query.findAllSorted("endDate", Sort.DESCENDING).first();
```

if database is empty?
I'm trying to get the last synchronization in Synchronization table. But if there isn't any record in table, I'm catching an exception.
What's the best way to do that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
RealmResults<Synchronization> results = query.findAllSorted("endDate", Sort.DESCENDING);
Synchronization obj = (result.size() > 0) ? result.first() : null;
```

Although I do agree that it could be a bit easier.

Comment: Hello Christian, thank you, but, in this way, realm get all the synchronizations in database, it could be better if it could return only the first directly.

Comment: is there an alternative? For example , the query may return null if there is no object in the database , instead of throwing an exception

Comment: The query never returns `null`. You will always get a `RealmResults`. It behaves just like a `List` so if it didn't find any matches `results.size() == 0`

Comment: I see there is no other solution that get all the objets and only after, get the first one ?

Comment: Yes, currently you can cannot do that in one operation.

Comment: What would be great is another method called `firstOrNull()`